# Generic way of updating python dictionary without overwriting the subdictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Is there any generic way to update python dictionary without overwriting the sub-dicts.
The dictionaries are dynamically generated hence, cannot predict the level, depth or subkeys in advance.

Consider following two dictionaries are generated dynamically -

```
d1 = {'a' : { 'b' : 'c'} }
d2 = {'a' : { 'd' : 'e'} }
```

If I call an update function the result would be something like this 
    d1.update(d2)
    print d1

Result =

```
{'a': {'d': 'e'}}
```

Expected Result =

```
{'a': {'b': 'c', 'd': 'e'}}
```

Above dictionaries are just for an example. The dictionaries could be of any level dynamically generated. Hence, provide if any in built function for python.. or some other way.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at http://pythonhosted.org/ete2/tutorial/tutorial_trees.html

Answer (score 1):

```
def update(d1,d2):
    c = d1.copy()
    for key in d2:
        if key in d1:c[key].update(d2[key])
        else:c[key] = d2[key]
    return c
```

Comment: I have modified my expected output.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no built-in for this. You can try something like this:

```
result = {key : [value, d2[key]] if key in d2 else value 
          for key,value in d1.items()}
```

Assuming you want a dictionary as a result (expected result in your question is not a valid Python construct).

Or:

```
result = {key : [value, d2[key]] if key in d2 else [value]
          for key,value in d1.items()}
```

if you want to always have a list as a value.

To merge nested dicts you can use this one-liner:

```
result = {key : value.update(d2[key]) or value if key in d2 else value
          for key,value in d1.items()}
```